# Map value in column to a dictionary value in other column

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I have one column that contains a dictionary (with value named "name", the other one is the new name that I want to update in the value from dictionary in column id.

I once tried to use multiprocessing but it seems to be difficult for million rows dataset

This is my expected result ('hd' to 'Honda', 'tyt' to 'Toyta'):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple loop:

```
for d, n in zip(df['id'], df['new_name']):
    d['name'] = n
```

Updated DataFrame:

```
                   id new_name
0   {'name': 'Honda'}    Honda
1  {'name': 'Toyota'}   Toyota
```

Comment: it'd good for a small dataframe. But I've had a huge dataset with more than 1 mil rows so I'm finding a fast solution

Comment: @CôngLý unfortunately, pandas is not designed to work with python objects, so this is the fastest you will get. You might be faster if you generate **new** dictionaries with `{'name': new_name}`, would this be a possibility?